# Synaptics touchpad disabled after update in Kubuntu

Tags: 11.10, synaptics

I have one Kubuntu computer running 11.10, after the updates a few days ago my synaptics touchpad died, it simply refuses to run, I am sure its a software thing because it works if I use a LiveCD.

Keyboard is working perfect, I can login, open a terminal and use my computer but would be nice to make the touchpad run again.

Anyone can guide me on where to find information and how to enable my touchpad again?

Comment: What does `synclient TouchpadOff=0` do for you.

Answer (score 2):

My one works after update, sounds like some software missing. You will know it better,
but have you tried `sudo dpkg -C` to look for half-installed packages?

Comment: Will try that, but I dont remember anything being held during the upgrade. Let you know later.

Comment: Hey, found it. Had x swat updates repo enabled and there was a bugged package on them. Thx for the suggestion here.